# How to get disk details from cygwin for a non-english windows using diskpart

Tags: windows, bash, shell, awk, cygwin

I have a scenario where there are windows OS in multiple languages... I need to get the disk details using a script, using diskpart in cygwin .. For english I use the following to get the details of the disk

```
while :
do
    echo "rescan" > $wscript
    echo "list disk" >> $wscript
    disks=$($diskpart /s $wscript | tee ${logfile} | awk 'p{print $2}$1~/^---/{p=1}')
    disk=""
    if [ ! -z "$disks" ]; then
        > $wscript
        for disk in $disks
        do
            echo "select disk $disk" >> $wscript
            echo "detail disk" >> $wscript
        done
        disk=$($diskpart /s $wscript | awk '/is now the selected disk/ {disk=$2} /^Target/ {if ($3 == target) print disk}' target=$target)
    fi
done
```

'target' is the disk number which I take for the script as an input. But when I use a non-english windows OS, the text comparison "/is now the selected disk/" doenst work as it is in a different language. Any idea to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable `LC_ALL` to `C`, which is the standard locale.

Comment: export LC_ALL=C didnt work :( The locale in cygwin changes to english but when I run diskpart in cygwin the results are still in original non-english language

Comment: Simply put `LC_ALL=C` at the top of your shell script.